# current time in python

Tags: python, email, time

Hi I want to add the current time and possibly date to an email message sent using python,
Its for a raspberry pi project i'm working on using an ultrasonic distance sensor,

I have the sensor placed on a meds box and if the box is moved a certain distance I want to send an email to myself with the text

"Your medicine box was moved at 04:15:32, Did you take your tablets?"

It works in so far as the email sends but the time looks like 041532

```
import smtplib
import time


def send_mail():

    content = "Your medication box has been moved " + str(
        time.strftime("%I" "%M" "%S")
    ) + "Did you take your tablets?"

    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('myEmailAddress', 'password')
    mail.sendmail('myEmaillAddress', 'myOtherEmailAddress', content)
    mail.close()
```

I tried adding colons to the time like so ("%I"":""%M"":""%S") but then the email was blank

Comment: Why so many quotes? What happens with `"%I:%M:%S"`

Comment: Just remove some quotes:  time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")

Comment: I tried it with one set of quotes "%I:%M%S" and the email appeared blank

Comment: Something is weird here, because this is supposed to work (with single quotes, as everyone here was saying). Can you add a `print(content)` to your code and tell us the result?

Comment: It will print to the console perfectly with "%I:%M:%S" but the email appears blank for some reason

Answer (score 3):

```
time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
```

essentially, the directives (the %X -es) get replaced with the respective values

Comment: I tried it with one set of quotes "%I:%M%S" and the email appeared blank

Comment: It will print to the console perfectly with "%I:%M:%S" but the email appears blank for some reason

Comment: oh yes, please fix your indentation. it may cause problems for your code too

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

str(datetime.now())
```

you'll find more in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: i tried 
content = "Your medication box has been moved " + str(datetime.now()) + " Did you take your tablets?"  

but again the email came in blank

Answer (score 0):

Don't add colons inside of the inverted commas. Doing it directly will work smoothly.

```
time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
```

And if you want it in **24-Hours Format**, just replace **%I with %H**. So it would look like this:

```
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```